# Adding angles in geometric figure

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

What angle should replace the green question mark sign in

[image]

Is it $10$ deg $+$ $15$ deg $= 25$ deg?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

The third angle in the triangle is $\theta = 180 - (10 + 15)$.  The green angle is supplementary to $\theta$ and so would be $180 - \theta = 25$.